# How to display a Mapbox map behind a navbar without losing ability to move around map?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a React (Next.js) project using Mapbox. I want to display a map (Map component supplied by react-map-gl) behind an opaque/transparent navbar.

I can get the desired visual effect by setting the z-index of the map component to -1. **However, I then lose the ability to move the map around.** I made a screen recording illustration this here: https://streamable.com/t3ghld. You can see that when I remove the z-index and the map overlaps the navbar, I can then click and drag to move around.

Here is the associated code:

```
import Map from "react-map-gl";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";

export default function MapMain() {
  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAP_KEY);
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Map
        initialViewState={{
          longitude: -122.4,
          latitude: 37.8,
          zoom: 14,
        }}
        style={{
          zIndex: -1,
          width: "100vw",
          height: "100vh",
        }}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
        mapboxAccessToken={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAP_KEY}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

I should also say that if I remove the position: fixed property from my navbar (as well as remove the z-index from the map since it isn't necessary), then it works fine, as shown here: https://streamable.com/z9ub53. I guess that would suffice, but I really want that transparent look if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making a separate component that contains only the Map component, like this:

```
import Map from "react-map-gl";

export default function MapFull() {
  return (
    <Map
      initialViewState={{
        longitude: -20,
        latitude: 25,
        zoom: 2,
      }}
      style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
      mapboxAccessToken={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAP_KEY}
    ></Map>
  );
}
```

Then in my map-main.js route, I include that component inside of a div with a few styles:

```
import MapFull from "@/components/maps/MapFull";

    export default function MapMain() {
      return (
        /* div container required to keep map working (interactive) with transparent navbar */
        <div style={{ position: "fixed", top: 0, zIndex: -1 }}>
          <MapFull />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

I've since moved the Navbar to a wrapper component, so that's why it's no longer included in the route/component above.